# Doxygen \cond not working

Tags: comments, doxygen

I am writing some documentation of some software in a `.dox` file and wand to include some comments that will not show in the webpage. I am using `\cond` but I am not getting any output after calling `\endcond`.

```
/// \section cuboids_sec Cuboids
///
/// \cond
///   [TODO]
/// \endcond
///
/// - \b Cuboid - Polyhedron bounded by six quadrilateral faces.
/// - \b Rectangular \b Cuboid - Cuboid with rectangular faces. 
///   Then each pair of adjacent faces meet in a right angle. By 
///   definition, a rectangular cuboid is also a right rectangular 
///   prism.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\cond` is to be used when you want to hide some code.

Internally doxygen will end the comment at `\cond` and restart a new comment block after `\endcond`. So the second part in your example does not belong to any page anymore.

For skipping part of a comment use `\if`:

```
/// \section cuboids_sec Cuboids
///
/// \if HIDDEN
///   [TODO]
/// \endif
///
/// - \b Cuboid - Polyhedron bounded by six quadrilateral faces.
/// - \b Rectangular \b Cuboid - Cuboid with rectangular faces. 
///   Then each pair of adjacent faces meet in a right angle. By 
///   definition, a rectangular cuboid is also a right rectangular 
///   prism.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

> For conditional sections within a comment block one should use a \if ... \endif block.

As stated in the documentation for `\cond`?